# Lsmeans producing identical p values when controlling for two other factors

Tags: r, lme4, lsmeans, posthoc, pairwise

Previously I have had no issues when using lsmeans to identify significant differences between groups while controlling for other factors using lme4 models. However, with the following dataset looking at fluoresence lsmeans produces identical p values regardless of other factor levels

A subset of the data used in this exmample can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-esLisG8EbTzA3cjVpRGtjREU/view?usp=sharing

Data

Response(s): here 1/0 presence/absence. (but also average pixel intensity and cbind precentage cover)

Fixed factor 1: heat treatment - 2 levels

Fixed factor 2: competition treatment - 2 levels

Fixed factor 3: time treatment - 2 levels

Random factor: none

Model creation

```
library(lme4)
model<-glm(presence ~ heat.treatment + competition.treatment + time.post.mating.hrs,  binomial(link= "logit"), data=gfptest)
```

Orginally interaction terms were included but their presence was non-significant based on AIC testing.  Using drop1 for significance testing on fixed factor removal heat is important

```
drop1(model, test= "Chi")
# presence ~ heat.treatment + competition.treatment + time.post.mating.hrs
#                      Df Deviance    AIC    LRT Pr(>Chi)   
#<none>                     30.589 38.589                   
#heat.treatment         1   39.114 45.114 8.5251 0.003503 **
#competition.treatment  1   30.876 36.876 0.2868 0.592297   
#time.post.mating.hrs   1   32.410 38.410 1.8206 0.177237
```

I would like to test for the difference between control and heat treaments while controlling for the competition treatment and time treatment eg. is presence significantly different between controls and heats at timepoint 0.5 hours and no competition, is presence significantly different between controls and heats at timepoint 24 hours and no competition, etc. I've tried lsmeans functions (multcomp yeilds similar results)

```
lsmeans(model, pairwise~heat.treatment+competition.treatment+time.post.mating.hrs, adjust="tukey")
```

and more explicitly

```
model <- lsmeans(model, "heat.treatment", by = "competition.treatment", at = list( time.post.mating.hrs = "0.5"))
modelsum<- summary(model, infer= c(TRUE,TRUE), level= .90, adjust= "bon", by="competition.treatment")
modelsum
```

pairs(model)

However, both give identical p values within each group combination; something which does not seem accurate when looking at boxplots and doing pairwise mann-whitney-U tests on data ranks

```
$contrasts
 contrast                                            estimate           SE df z.ratio p.value
control,single,0.5 - heat,single,0.5              18.3718560 2224.3464134 NA   0.008  1.0000
control,competition,0.5 - heat,competition,0.5    18.3718560 2224.3464134 NA   0.008  1.0000
control,single,24 - heat,single,24                18.3718560 2224.3464134 NA   0.008  1.0000
control,competition,24 - heat,competition,24      18.3718560 2224.3464134 NA   0.008  1.0000
```

I have tried exploring the dataframe to eliminate the cause of identical p-values. The issue is still apparent with reducing the number of factors to two and using a different response variable/error distribution.

Any help with resolving the lsmean/similar package issue would be appreciated. As a secondary option any advice on whether its acceptable to do poisson/binomial glm()s then follow up post-hoc testing with  t-test/mann-whitneys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems very odd that you would note that the P values are all the same and apparently did not notice that the estimated differences and standard errors are all the same. Most people look at those first. (If you didn't, I recommend it highly; we should talk about effects and such, the P values are just accessories.)

Anyway, the explanation is that you fitted an *additive* model -- one with no interactions. Such a model specifies that the effect of one factor is exactly the same, regardless of the levels of any other factor. And that is exactly what you are seeing.

In short, this has nothing to do with `lsmeans()` and everything to do with the model you fitted.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Yes I agree about effect sizes and also noticed they were the same but failed to emphasise it. I would also report effect sizes, and sample sizes in the write up. The p value focus seems to be the culture in my field.

I’ve removed the interactions because their inclusion did not significantly improve the AIC and have been cautioned against the complexity of interpreting 3-factor interactions. Thanks for the explaination of why the estimates are the same.

Comment: Looking back where I’ve used lsmeans it has been mainly with comparing groups within one factor.


    model<-glm(Frequency ~ Temperature.oC, poisson(link = "log"), data)
    lsmeans(model, pairwise~Temperature.oC, adjust="tukey")


or two factors with interactions    model <-glmer(Adult.count.20D ~ Temperature.oC * Days.between.heat.mate + (Days.between.heat.mate|Replicate), family = poisson(link = log))     lsmeans(model, pairwise~Temperature.oC*Days.between.heat.mate, adjust="tukey")

Comment: We would still like to compare the control and heat treatments within each of the categories (0.5+single, 0.5+competition, 24+single, 24+competiton). Please could you advise alternative packages/methods which could achieve this from the model object. Or if the interactions need to be retained in order to do this. 
Alternatively whether it is acceptable two report the model summary for factors then doing mann-whitney-us/t-tests/glms() within subsets of the data. 

Thanks again for help, answering qs below should solve issue

Comment: If you’re satisfied with the model, then it is silly to break down the comparisons that way. The marginal comparison of heat treatments is adequate — and SIMPLE. Making parsimonious conclusions is preferable over complicated ones, as long as they apply. I suspect that even if you put the interactions back in the model, you still won’t have any significant comparisons. If you try that, use as “by” variables *only* the ones that interact with heat.